# Can't mass-assign protected attributes ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

This is my error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email, password,   password_confirmation/Users/judyngai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@spreeversion/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
```

I am just going through this quick start guide.

http://www.railsmine.net/2011/07/activeadmin-tutorial.html

I don't have an existing rails app with models/tables that I am "synchronizing the dashboard with"

I am using ruby 1.9.3p429 and Rails 3.2.13.

I made a new blog app, installed the gem, install active admin and got the error after running rake db:migrate

I am not building anything particular with activeadmin. I just want to test the admin dashboard out and with eventually adding some quick tables that I plan to filter through.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add `attr_accessible  :email, :password, :password_confirmation` to your `Adminuser` model (`app/models/admin_user.rb`).

Comment: What about security though? Can you do this for a specific role using, for example `:as => :active_admin`?

Comment: There we go... https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/536#issuecomment-4831597